# Can we somehow make "layout_weight" but for width?

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

In Android Studio, with Linear Layout, using layout_weight - I can solve my problems very easy ( setting layout_weight for every view how much I need ), but I struggle with layout_width ( on one screen app looks good but on another screen not ), it little overwhelming for beginners to understand the dp, sp, px etc. Can we somehow make "layout_weight" but for width?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication3.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="The title will be here "  

 //The length of this text up here is permanent, and is 23 characters, also 
 //that much length for the texts in TextViews in other Linear Layouts below
 //While in all CheckBoxes in all Layouts the text is same and permanent and
 //will contain 7 characters.
 //Also i will add a onClick in ImageView.

        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze_black_24dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="CheckBox1"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="The title will be here "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze_black_24dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="CheckBox2"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="The title will be here "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze_black_24dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="CheckBox3"
        android:textColor="#E91E63"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your XML so we can suggest you correct way

Comment: learn how to use Constraint layouts ...https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013

Comment: and yes you can use weights for width ... just weight_sum to root view and layout width = 0dp and assign weight

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Instead of setting `android:layout_height` to zero, set the `android:layout_width`. And work the same way you do for the height, but for the width.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use **layout_weight** for individual component; make sure that you are using **weightsum** attribute in the root tag declaration.

When you using layout_weight:

1. Provide **layout_width=0dp** in the same component for horizontal orientation
2. **layout_height=0dp** for vertical orientation.
3. Mixing layout_weight along the **layout_height/layout_width** having values either **wrap_contet/match_parent** do not give the correct look